# Having trouble searching a text file for strings

Tags: java, string, search, text-files, search-keywords

So I'm attempting to simulate a very basic search engine by reading a text file filled with data and then have a user search the file using some keywords, and then whichever "websites" contained in the text file that contain that keyword are returned back to the user. My code so far  can read the text file (as far as I know), however no matter the entered keyword, the console almost always states that no results can be found (the text file doesn't contain the keyword(s). Thanks everyone.

Here's the appropriate code:

```
package myquery;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyQuery{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String> > hash = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String> >();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Here is where your .txt file(s) should be located for this program to work properly:");
    System.out.println(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("\nEnter the filename that you want to Search values for. For example \"MyQuery.txt\"");
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input.nextLine()));
        System.out.println("The file was found :) Here are the contents:");

        while(reader.ready())
        {
            String currentline = reader.readLine();
            String[] result = currentline.split("\\s");
            for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                if(!hash.containsKey(result[i]))
                {
                    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(1);
                    temp.add(currentline);
                    hash.put(result[i], temp);
                }
                else
                {
                    ArrayList<String> temp = (ArrayList<String>)hash.get(result[i]);//
                    temp.add(currentline);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Your file was not found unfortunately. Please try again.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println(hash);
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a key to search for the value it is associated with.\n");
        System.out.println(hash.get(input.nextLine()));
        System.out.println("\nWant to try again? If so, press return and then follow the prompt. Type \"-1\" to quit");
    }
    while(!input.nextLine().equals("-1"));
    try
    {
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

And an example of one line in the text file:

```
www.Mets.com, "The New York Mets", baseball, team, NY
```

Here's an example of how the program should respond:

```
Enter a key to search for the value it is associated with.

Mets
www.Mets.com The New York Mets

Want to try again? If so, press return and then follow the prompt. Type "-1" to quit
```

But here's what I'm getting instead:

```
Enter a key to search for the value it is associated with:

Mets
null

Want to try again? If so, press return and then follow the prompt. Type "-1" to quit
```

ALTHOUGH. If I enter a word that matches any word besides the first/last ones, it works.

For example

```
Enter a key to search for the value it is associated with:

New
[www.Mets.com, "The New York Mets", baseball, team, NY, www.nytimes.com, "The New York Times", news]

Want to try again? If so, press return and then follow the prompt. Type "-1" to quit
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in your IDE debugger?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with it to be quite honest with you-I can experiment and see what I find. Good idea :)

Comment: Learning how to use the debugger is a _fundamental requirement_ for writing ANY software.  Please make it a priority, it will make your life a LOT easier.  Without the debugger you will always be crawling, with the debugger you can run, and watching what happens at each step will teach you a lot about computing.

Comment: Hint: making experiments (for example using simple print statements to observe what is going on) ... is the **essence** of becoming a programmer. Turning to other people to ask them "please debug my stuff for me" is like the ultimate last resort to take. Not the first one!

Comment: Do you get *The file was found :) Here are the contents:* ?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yep. The program works properly but only if I enter a string which is contained within parenthesis and also not the first/last word. Strange...

Comment: please provide an example of file content and words with which it doesn't work

Comment: @NicolasFilotto alright I believe that should make it easier, it's updated :)

Comment: Use this currentline.split("\\W+") instead of currentline.split("\\s")

Comment: It works because with `\\s` you will get words of type *Mets",* instead of *Mets* as you expect